# Import Shapefile to GDB. OGR2OGR FGDB Driver bug(?) on CentOS 7

Tags: file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, linux, centos

I used ogr2ogr to convert shapefiles to fgdb feature classes.
I have like 10 of shapefiles so I imported the folder (input as a folder directory) and converted to FGDB
This is the code I used

`ogr2ogr -progress -overwrite -f "FileGDB" $HOME/MyData/Output.gdb "$HOME/MyData/MyShapefiles/";`

`ogrinfo $HOME/MyData/Output.gdb` seems like I have all the layers that I want to convert

However, check out the screenshot below.
This is the original shapefile

[image]

This is the one in Geodatabase
[image]

something has changed and I overlayed the two layers
[image]

Is this a bug? or is this centOS's issue??

Comment: Looks like a spatial reference selection error.  Please [Edit] the question to specify both the coordinate system (.prj) and spatial reference parameters used in the target feature class.

Comment: Esri geodatabases have a concept of [resolution / tolerance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/the-properties-of-a-spatial-reference.htm). These "won't effect any OGR operations, but they will by used by ArcGIS" ([OGR FileGDB docs](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html)). I wonder if these parameters are a significant factor here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is because of setting the projection.

The original Shapefile comes without .prj and that is the reason why.
I added the epsg and now seems fine.

Sorry for the trouble.
this is the code I used

`ogr2ogr -progress -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:**** -t_srs EPSG:**** -f "FileGDB" $HOME/MyData/Output.gdb "$HOME/MyData/MyShapefiles/"`